# array.push is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  let guildMembers = [];
  response.guild.members.forEach(async m => {
    let userResponse;
    try {
      userResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=KEY&uuid=${m.uuid}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    userResponse = userResponse.data;
    if(userResponse.success != true) return res.send('Error with API.');
    userResponse = userResponse.player;
    var guildRank = m.rank;
    guildRank = guildRank.toLowerCase();
    guildRank = guildRank.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + guildRank.slice(1);
    guildMembers.push(`${userResponse.displayname} | ${guildRank}`);
  });
```

Why does this return `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: guildMembers.push is not a function`?

I tried doing `` console.log(`${userResponse.displayname} | ${guildRank}`); `` right before `` guildMembers.push(`${userResponse.displayname} | ${guildRank}`); `` and it logged what is supposed to be added correctly.

Comment: The problem is not the value you are trying to push. Is the array itself. You are modifying `guildMembers` somewhere so is not an array anymore. Try to create a minimum, reproducible example, step by step following your code and I'm sure you will find it ;-)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Simply you are doing `guildMembers = whatever` somewhere. If you don't know how to find it, just get your code, reduce it to just the script you posted until it works (minimum), then add tiny bits of code and see when it fails (reproducible).

Comment: Also, adding on top to Jorge's comment: try using `const guildMembers = []` and see if you get an error. Chances are, like what Jorge's said, somewhere in your code you are reassigning `guildMembers` into something that is not an array.

Comment: @Terry Oh yeah, the magic of `const`. God bless ES6 hahaha.

Comment: Terry's fix actually worked. I don't think there is a way to mark a comment as an answer, but thanks!

Comment: Terry comment is not a fix, but a way to find the actual problem. The problem still persists if you don't removed the `guildMembers = whatever` you have elsewhere. Adding `const` and not fixing the actual problem will surely lead to another problems. I don't know if you done so, but pointing out just in case, so you don't stop in StackOverflow again because of this haha.

Comment: Yes, it helped me find the issue and how to fix it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the `for..of loop` or the traditionally for loop. ForEach seems to be `read only`.